# how to call a dialog from another dialog

Tags: android

I have a class on which I have a map object. I send this map object to a custom Dialog. After that I want to call another dialog from this dialog, but the second dialog is not showing. I don't know where i m doing wrong.

Activity :

```
dlgi = new MyCommunityServicesDialog(AppCentral.this, myValues, mapView);
dlgi.listDialog().show();
```

Custom Dialog :

```
Community_List_Dialog dialog = new Community_List_Dialog(context, getAllCommunityNames(selectedOpt).get(0), getAllCommunityNames(selectedOpt).get(1), mapView)
dialog.showDialog();
```

NOTE : This method (`getAllCommunityNames(selectedOpt).get(0)/(1)`) returns `String[]`.

Custom Dialog Second :

```
public Dialog showDialog()
{

    Log.i("listDialog calling...", "calling...");
    final Dialog community_dialog = new Dialog(context);
    community_dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    community_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.community_list);
    ListView community_list = (ListView)community_dialog.findViewById(R.id.community_list);

    adapter = new Community_List_Adapter(context,names);
    community_list.setAdapter(adapter);

    return community_dialog;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was making use of the class

```
android.os.AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
```

Description is given in die JavaDoc:

"AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers."

By using the methods `onPreExecute()` you can manipulate View on the UI Thread.

After finishing this method, `doInBackground()` is invoked and here you can start your background operations. This method is not working on the UI Thread, so it is not blocking your application.

After this `onPostExecute()` is invoked and you can use your computeted results.

My problem was to correctly show a progress indicator while the background oeprations are made. This can be done by making use of the `onProgressUpdate()` method, which is working ob the UI Thread, while the background computations are made.

Comment: Soryy to say but I think  there is no requirement top use AsyncTask here. I have an activity, from which I am calling a cuatom dialog. From this dialog, I am calling another dialog. But the last dialog is not showing. I don't know why but I think that the I am wrong. You can see the code for further information.when I dismiss first dialog.